# Python/Django installation is not happening

Tags: python, django

I newly installed python 2.7 and django 1.3.Django 1.3 was insatalled from this comand

```
yum install Django MySQL-python
```

installation was said it is completed sucessfully.But after that i am trying to create a database table using the command

```
   python manage.py syncdb
```

I am getting the following traceback

```
[root@localhost DemoApp]# python manage.py syncdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 429, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 191, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 219, in execute
    self.validate()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 249, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 102, in get_validation_errors
    connection.validation.validate_field(e, opts, f)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/validation.py", line 14, in validate_field
    db_version = self.connection.get_server_version()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 338, in get_server_version
    self.cursor()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 250, in cursor
    cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 322, in _cursor
    self.connection = Database.connect(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 187, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1049, "Unknown database 'DemoApp'")
```

can any one tell me what would be the cause of this problem,any wrong in installation

Comment: have you created a database called DemoApp in mysql ? You need to create the database and give the user permissions on the database you wish to access through django

Comment: database was not created,while creating database i am getting this error.I am using mysql

Comment: Yes, i understand that. Django would not create a database for you. It only creates the tables. You have to create the database explicitly either by MySQL Query Browser, or the command line

Comment: @Kartick may i know how to create database please

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-database.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/#database-setup):

> If you’re using PostgreSQL or MySQL, make sure you’ve created a database by this point. Do that with “CREATE DATABASE database_name;” within your database’s interactive prompt.
>
> If you’re using SQLite, you don’t need to create anything beforehand - the database file will be created automatically when it is needed.

So, you need to create the database first to have syncdb load the data.

To create the database, run the `mysql` program. This gives you a command prompt for interacting with your SQL database. Then you run...

```
create database DemoApp;
```

For more info on doing this, see the MySQL tutorial on [Connecting and Disconnecting from the Server](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connecting-disconnecting.html) and [Creating and Selecting a Database](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/creating-database.html).